# How to connect to WIFI but use phone mobile internet?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, chromecast, oneplus-two, oxygenos

My WIFI internet is very slow. 
I would like to use my mobile internet of my phone, but connect to my wifi because it has Google Cast in it.

Phone: Oneplus 2
OS: OO 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an option called **Smart network switch** which switches to mobile data connection whenever the WiFi connectivity is limited or unstable.

The screenshot below is from Samsung Galaxy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it on Android, just a bit of imagination and effort:

- Open WIFI, touch and hold your Wifi network (Options should appear)
- Select *Manage Network Settings*
- Then *Show advanced options*
- Select *Static* under *IP Settings option*
- Save the changes

***I just made an adaptation from this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173894/can-i-connect-to-wifi-but-still-use-cellular). I never tested it myself, but SHOULD work. Just give it a try.***

*The snapshots are from Samsung Galaxy on Marshmallow (6.0.1). It may be different on other phone model/Android version.*

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

Comment: Please, see the wiki answer. OO interface is so limited that it does not have such basic network configuration options. So no imagination helps here. - - Thank you for pointing out this! - - This will help others to make better decisions about their phones, since the company itself does not want to highlight these weaknesses.

Comment: How does a static IP address allow one to switch to Mobile data while on WiFi?

Comment: @user145490 According to the post linked above, this tells the [iPhone] that it should use its cellular network to route internet traffic rather than trying to do it via WiFi. I still not sure if its the same on Android.

Comment: @user145490 Making an IP address static lets you edit or customize it settings. Cause a dynamic address has it settings set by the DCHP server. I think that's why they are recommending to make the address static

Comment: As @user145490 already pointed out, assigning a static IP address to the WiFi interfaces just does one thing: it makes WiFi using that static address. It doesn't change a thing about how mobile traffic is handled, or via which interface traffic is routed. I even go as far as to doubt the same for the iPhone, as that's a general networking rule. If you insist it should work, please try it yourself and [edit] your post with results from that. On Android, as soon as a stable WiFi is available, mobile data is switched off by default – regardless of whether the IP is static or dynamic.

Comment: @Izzy The only purpose of assigning a static address is because it can let you edit its settings! on a dynamic address there is no way to change anything as the DCHP server already setup everything.

Comment: Exactly. And how does that make the device using mobile data instead? Unless you're setting it up in a way it cannot work (wrong DNS/Gateway), it won't change WiFi *from being used.* And if you set it up wrongly (so it cannot work), that's achieved much easier by simply turning it off – which defeats the purpose of the question.

Comment: BTW: Why does that work on the iPhone? Due to a detail you've missed: ***Make sure you leave Router, DNS, and Search Domains blank!*** So what does this do? Make WiFi "dead": no route anymore (as no router/gateway). As I described above: That's easier to achieve by simply turning WiFi off :)

Comment: I don't own an iDevice to test, on Android I already have the option that switch Wifi to mobile connection. And in my post I claim never tested it. All is clear

Comment: So why don't they simply say: Yo, Just switch your Wifi and everything is fine?

Answer (score 0):

Chat with OO support

> After reviewing the link you provided and checking the current features running through the OnePlus Phones, we currently don't have this right now however will be able to raise this over to our developers team to check if this is possible in the near future.

There is no such feature in OO as in Android shown [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/161570/9897)

[image]

No imagination can do a work which does not exist.

Comment: This post, although related to iPhone, may be helpful: http://www.google.cd/url?q=http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173894/can-i-connect-to-wifi-but-still-use-cellular&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiE0vjlrZHQAhWFvRoKHSZWDfQQFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNH4mtEW4OWantebGMDm30jkNN7WHg

Comment: Sounds promising but I could not find anywhere similar parameters as in iPhone.

Comment: The point here is to make your Wifi Network connection as static. This will tell your phone  to route internet traffic.

Comment: @es Yes, it is a great proposal but I cannot find an option to make the connection static in my phone.

Comment: I opened a new thread about the issue here http://android.stackexchange.com/q/161569/9897

Comment: @esQmo As per my knowledge, making your device operate on a static IP doesn't really prevent internet from functioning.

Comment: @user145490 You didn't read the post, did you?

Comment: It seems to work on iOS.

Comment: @esQmo Actually I have read the post. But you need to understand that assigning a static IP address to your device simply tells the router this is my address don't give it to anyone else, and if you have, take it from them. This doesn't prevent you from accessing internet. If you note, he didn't change the DNS address meaning theoretically it remained 0.0.0.0 resulting in no internet. This is because the data is being sent to an address that does not exist(0.0.0.0) and thus the webpage can't be translated to a readable address where the webpage will be found.

Comment: @esQmo I asked how assigning a static IP address would result in no internet. I just wanted to know how exactly this was to happen because as from what I know it shouldn't. Despite getting your answer from another source and it being marked as an answer, try and substantiate those facts either by trying it yourself or providing proof on it. Like a definite explanation.

Comment: I think making it static so that it won't be changed or affected to another device by the router. And I my post i say I never tested it although it works. And everyone recommend setting the IP as static.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48026/discussion-between-user145490-and-esqmo).

Comment: I got it now: Making an IP address static lets you edit or customize its settings. Cause a dynamic address has it settings set by the DCHP server. I think that's why they are recommending to make the address static