# How to make Android WIFI connection static and use always mobile internet?

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, connection-issues, oneplus-two, oxygenos

I want to use always my mobile internet although I am connected to the wifi network. 
So I want to make my connection static.

OS: OO 3.1
Phone: Oneplus 2
Related thread: [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/161563/9897)

Comment: @beeshyams Make the IP static instead of using DHCP. He's trying to use both WiFi and mobile connection and route all internet to mobile data connection.

Comment: @esQmo: Got it after reading the linked post // OP try [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1667025) requires root

Comment: [Speedify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedify.speedifyandroid) claims to combine mobile and WiFi. That may work for you as your WiFi is not good enough anyway. Not tried by me

Comment: @beeshyams Please, make your proposal an answer. I will review it now for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked post your WiFi is not good enough, so *combining* WiFi and mobile data may work

[Speedify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedify.speedifyandroid) claims to do this ( not tried by me)

> Combine your Wi-Fi and Mobile Data Connections for Fast Unbreakable Connectivity